# How to make sure that state is never empty with hooks and await?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I am using acios to fetch data from an API and update the value of my hooks. The initial value is set to an empty object. I thought that if I use "await" before the axios request that the function will not progress before the request is fetched and the new values are set.

Unfortunately this does not always happen and "values" sometimes stays empty even after the axios get-request should have been awaited.

How do I make sure that values os mever "{}" in the code? I thought "await" should fix that but it did not.

```
import { Grid, Hidden } from '@material-ui/core';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import ProjectInformation from '../../projects/components/ProjectInformation';
import axios from 'axios';

const style = {
    textAlign: 'left',
    float: 'right',
    position: 'fixed',
};

export default function ProjectPage(props) {
    const propsId = props.match.params.id;

    const [values, setValues] = useState({});
    useEffect(() => {
        getProjectById();
    }, []);

    const getProjectById = async () => {
        const { data } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:9000/projects/${propsId}`);
        setValues(data);
    };

    console.log('values are', values);

    return (
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Hidden smDown>
                <Grid item sm={2}>
                    <div style={style}>
                        <Link href="#anchor1">Project Information</Link>
                        <br />
                        <Link href="#anchor2">Fieldwork Information</Link>
                        <br />
                        <Link href="#anchor3">Personell & Institutions</Link>
                        <br />
                        <Link href="#anchor4">Project Updates</Link>
                        <br />
                        <Link href="#anchor5">Datasets</Link>
                        <br />
                        <Link href="#anchor6">Publications</Link>
                    </div>
                </Grid>
            </Hidden>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={10} style={{ borderLeft: '1px solid #dddddd' }}>
                <Grid item>
                    <div id="anchor1">
                        <ProjectInformation props={values} />
                    </div>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                    <div id="anchor2">
                        <p>test</p>
                    </div>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                    <div id="anchor3">
                        <p>test</p>
                    </div>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                    <div id="anchor4">
                        <p>test</p>
                    </div>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                    <div id="anchor5">
                        <p>test</p>
                    </div>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                    <div id="anchor6">
                        <p>test</p>
                    </div>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    );
}
```

Comment: this should help : 
`if(data){
 setValues(data);
}`

Comment: everything looks pretty solid, can you maybe create a jsfiddle which simulates the issue?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, whenever a React component is bootstrapped if you define state with some values ie: `this.state = {something: "something else"};` then it has that state at initialization. If your data for state depends on an async request, the initial state wouldn't have that value, and I don't think that merely using `async` and `await` will prevent that, since React doesn't run the code until after the component mounts.

From the docs:

> If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods,
>   you can think of useEffect Hook as componentDidMount,
>   componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount combined.

Answer (score 1):

You can either do one of the following:

`data? setValues(data) : null;`

or

`data && setValues(data);`